# ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated - child record found - fetchType issue?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a small issue with deleting from a table which has several child entities.

I have a table with the name UNIVERSITY and one with the name STUDENT.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "university", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private University university;
```

I whish to delete a row from the table University:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void deleteFromUniveristy(Long id) {
    em.createNamedQuery(University.DELETE_BY_ID)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .executeUpdate();
}

@NamedQuery(name = University.DELETE_BY_ID, query = "delete from University uu where uu.id =:id")
```

But a receive the error message:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated - child record found
```

I do not understand, the orphanRemoval = true and the given CascadeType does not garantee to be this deletion possible?

Thank you!

Comment: The University table doesn't have any field that acts as a foreign key for any other table right? Because if so, then you have to delete such entries first.

Comment: Is there a way to delete all the child entities at the same time automatically with the deletion of the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete parent with child is possible using `entityManager.remove(entity)` method. Cascading does not work in delete JPQL.